# How to instantiate 3 gameobjects in 3 positions of a list of 20 random positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to instantiate 3 gameobjects in 3 positions of a list of 20 random positions. When I play the game it’s instantiating 20 gameobjects in 20 positions, and not 3 gameobjects. How can I do it? This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpawnManager: MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject Player;

public List<GameObject> spawnPositions;
public List<GameObject> spawnObjects;

void Start()
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        SpawnObjects ();
    }
}

void SpawnObjects()
{
    foreach (GameObject spawnPosition in spawnPositions) 
    {
        int selection = Random.Range (0, spawnObjects.Count);
        Instantiate (spawnObjects [selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation);
    }
}
}
```

UPDATE:

Sometimes 2 objects are placed in the same position and I want the objects to instantiate in different positions. I've tried to add the random positions to a list and only instantiate if it isn't already in the list, but it doesn't work. This is my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class SpawnManager : MonoBehaviour {

private GameObject Player;

public List<GameObject> spawnPositions;
public List<GameObject> spawnObjects;

private GameObject obj;

void Start()
{
    Player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
    {
        SpawnObjects ();
    }
}

void SpawnObjects()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        int randomObject = Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Count);
        int randomPosition = Random.Range(0, spawnPositions.Count);

        List <GameObject> _spawnPositions = new List<GameObject>();

        obj = spawnPositions[randomPosition];

        _spawnPositions.Add(obj);

        if (!_spawnPositions.Contains (obj)) 
        {
            Instantiate (spawnObjects [randomObject], _spawnPositions [randomPosition].transform.position, _spawnPositions [randomPosition].transform.rotation);
        } 

        else 
        {
            Debug.Log ("error");
        }

    }
}

}
```

Comment: You're looping over all of the positions and adding random objects to them, you need to randomise that as well.

Comment: `int rnd = /*random integer*/; foreach(var spawnPoint in spawnPositions.OrderBy(g => rnd).Take(3)) { /*your instantiate code*/ }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looping over all of the positions and adding random objects to them, you need to randomise that as well. So this:

```
foreach (GameObject spawnPosition in spawnPositions) 
{
    int selection = Random.Range (0, spawnObjects.Count);
    Instantiate (spawnObjects [selection], spawnPosition.transform.position, spawnPosition.transform.rotation);
}
```

Should be this:

```
int randomObject = Random.Range(0, spawnPositions.Count);
int randomPosition = Random.Range(0, spawnPositions.Count);

Instantiate (spawnObjects[randomObject], spawnPositions[randomPosition].transform.position, spawnPositions[randomPosition].transform.rotation);
```

And then just put that in a for loop like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
```

In your updated code you're creating the list on each loop, you need to use the same list (untested but should work):

```
List<int> randomObjects = new List<int>();
List<int> randomPositions = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
{
    int randomObject;
    do
    {
        randomObject = Random.Range(0, spawnObjects.Count);
    }
    while (randomObjects.Contains(randomObject));
    randomObjects.Add(randomObject);

    int randomPosition;
    do
    {
        randomPosition = Random.Range(0, spawnPositions.Count);
    }
    while (randomPositions.Contains(randomPosition));
    randomPositions.Add(randomPosition);

    Instantiate(spawnObjects[randomObject], spawnPositions[randomPosition].transform.position, spawnPositions[randomPosition].transform.rotation);
}
```